# If condition is met, variable needs to be within a specific range

Tags: idl-programming-language

I am brand new to IDL, and find that the documentation online is lacking in comparison to other languages. This is also my very first post on stackoverflow, so I will do my best to include the proper information necessary to answer my question. I'm doing research on the spectra of galaxies. In the code I am working on, we have 5 different indices, 0 through 4. Each index is for a different spectral feature. I am trying to input into the code that **if the index is 4 (ff EQ 4) then 0.02 < z < 0.03 or z > 0.04**, but no other values of z should be allowed for this specific feature.

**How can I input this condition for this index properly? **

I have tried:
`if (ff EQ 4) then (z GT 0.02 AND z LT 0.03) OR (z GT 0.04)`

and:
`for ff=4 do begin z GT 0.02 AND z LT 0.03 OR z GT 0.04`

and a couple of variations of the above. I put the 'endfor' or the 'endif' a little further down the code. Neither of these approaches have worked for me. I thought that maybe the if statement could only handle two statements after the condition, but I also  tried:
`if (ff EQ 4) then z GT 0.03 AND z LT 0.03`

which also did not work. The errors have almost all been syntax errors.

Is there a way to make a statement similar to this:
`if (ff EQ 4) then begin 0.02<z<0.03 OR z>0.04`
??

I just need the variable 'z' to meet those conditions whenever the index is 4. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I really hope this makes sense and that I have included the proper information. If not, please let me know what else I can include to help you better understand my problem. I also want to apologize in advance for my naivety when it comes to IDL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this, where `&&` is the logical `and` operator and `||` is the logical `or` operator:

```
if ((ff eq 4) && ((z gt 0.02 && z lt 0.03) || (z gt 0.04))) then begin
  ; do whatever it is
endif
```

Comment: This is very helpful to know -- thank you for the information!! However, I actually want something more along the lines of: "when (ff eq 4) then ((z gt 0.02 && lt 0.03) || (z gt 0.04))". I just need z to be within those ranges when ff is 4. I am not sure how to code that up here.

Comment: But z might not be in your ranges. An IF statement lets you do something if a condition is met. Do you want to print an error or crash or something if z is not in your ranges?